# How can I *ngFor Iterate through this Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, typescript

I have a  like this

```
<div class="containers" *ngFor="goes here">

<div #arr1>
<p>{{item.a}}</p>

   p2

<p>{{item.a}}</p>
</div>

</div>
```

I have an array that looks like this

```
arr = [
[{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 2, b: 2}],
[{a: 5, b: 2}, {a: 1, b: 2}]
]
```

I would like to get angular to do something like this

```
<div class="containers" *ngFor="goes here">

<div>
<p>{{item.a}}</p>
<p>{{item.a}}</p>
</div>

<div>
<p>{{item.a}}</p>
<p>{{item.a}}</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Regular *ngFor wont work, since it's obviously an array of arrays and not an array of objects. With this being known, I would need to index into the particular arrays, which won't be to glamorous .

How can I get this done ?

Comment: ngFor="let item of data"